# Removing the root squares from this expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to understand how to remove the root squares from this expression:

$$x = \frac 1{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}}$$

How to do it?

Comment: The right expression is the actual one. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its all about rationalization,

\begin{align}
\frac 1{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}} &= \frac 1{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}}
\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}
\\[10pt] &=\frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2-(\sqrt{5})^2}
\\[10pt] &=\frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}{(2+3+2\sqrt{6})-(5)}
\\[10pt] &=\frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{6}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt6}
\\[10pt]&=\frac{\sqrt{12}+ \sqrt{18} - \sqrt{30}}{12}
\\[10pt]&=\frac{2\sqrt{3} + 3\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{30}}{12}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the entire calculus.

Comment: In the 4th line, you could have just multiplied by $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{6}}$ instead

Answer (score 3):

Here's a push

You can try rationalising it by multiplying the expression by its conjugate.

$$\frac 1{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}}\times\frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}}=\frac {\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3}- \sqrt{5}}{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2-(\sqrt{5})^2}$$
and you can continue it.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac 1{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}}=\frac {\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3}- \sqrt{5}}{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2-(\sqrt{5})^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3} - \sqrt5}{2\sqrt{6}}$ I think you can do the rest.

Comment: Can you explain a little more how you get the second expression from the first one?

Comment: I multiplied numerator and denominator with $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}$. It is well-known trick, that if you have $\sqrt{K} \pm \sqrt{L}$ on denominator it is reasonable to multiply up and down of fraction with $\sqrt{K} \mp \sqrt{L}$. Actually you can do the same if you have just $K$ instead of $\sqrt{K}$.

Answer (score 0):

Given expression $$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5}=\frac{\sqrt 5+\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2}{(\sqrt 5+\sqrt 3)^2-2}\\=\frac{\sqrt 5+\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2}{6+2\sqrt{15}}=\frac{(\sqrt 5+\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2)(6-2\sqrt{15})}{-24}$$